# Xcode- Implicit conversion from long long to long changes value from 10,000,000,000,000 to 1,575,856,128

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use a very large value (10 Trillin) however it changes the value to 1,575,856,128 when running the app on the iPhone 4s. However it works fine on the iPhone 5 and above.

All I did was declare

```
long number1;
```

And then set it equal to the value

```
number1 = 10000000000000
```

Comment: Change `number1` to `long long` instead of `long`.

Comment: Now the problem is that I'm trying to store this value using NSUserDefaults and now I'm getting implicit conversion loses integer precision. Will the NSUserDefaults not store the proper number?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` doesn't directly support `long long` values. You could wrap the `long long` in an `NSNumber` and store the `NSNumber` in `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether device Bus frequency and width is 32-bit / 64-bit.

- **In 32 bit** environment **long** is 4 bytes, maximum positive value of long = 2^32 / 2 - 1 = 2147483647
- **In 64 bit** environment **long** is 8 bytes, maximum positive value of long = 2^64 / 2 - 1 = 9223372036854775807

Refer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html

in 32-bit environment, If you pass long value that is greater than 2147483647 (<10000000000000). it will be truncated

but **long long** is 8 bytes in both 32-bit / 64-bit environment (so can keep value upto 9223372036854775807)